# How to hide Thumbnail view option in Active reports 6.0

Tags: c#, activereports

I am working with a Windows application. In this application I have to show some reports. For showing the reports, I am using Active reports viewer 6.0.

Now, my problem is about the table of content area in Active report viewer. I want to hide the thumbnail view option and table of content tab below the content area of Active report viewer.

I am attaching an image for better understanding of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize the tableOfContent in Active Report viewer, firstly we have to get all control from viewer and then get the Tab Control and work on TabPage.

var controls = viewer1.Controls.Cast();
foreach (Control control in controls)

```
{
  // Check fot TableOfContents Control
  if (control.Name == "TableOfContents")
 {
                        // Getting the TabControl.
                        var contColletion = control.Controls;
                        Control tabCollection = contColletion[0];
                        TabControl tabControl = (TabControl)tabCollection;
                        tabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.Normal;
                        // Remove the Thumbnail Tab from Control.
                        tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(1);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the toc button on the viewer toolbar (left of print button).  You can also do this through api.

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.Viewer~TableOfContents.html